# Multiple linear regression interpretation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference

I don't know how to interpret the confidence intervals of the dishwas_betw variable?  How to interpret the low significance values like for the DVAge variable?

[image]

Comment: The SE (or SD) is always non-negative. Are you thinking about a confidence interval (CI)?

Comment: @user2974951 many thanks - yes

Comment: Try using `confint()` on your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as the intercept is a negative value.

The interecept is not negative. It is 3.9

The estimate for `dishwas_betw` is -0.29. Thus for every 1 unit change in the value of `dishwas_betw`, we expeect a change of -0.29 in the response/outcome, when `work_minutes` is zero and when `work_minutes_squared` is also zero (this is a consequence of interacting `dishwas_betw`with both `work_minutes` and `work_minutes_squared`. If it does not make sense in your study for `work_minutes` to be zero, then you may want to consider centering it around it's mean, so that it is more easily interpreted.

If you want to compute confidence intervals then you can use the `confint` function.

Note that you seem to have a problem with the `employment` variable resulting in a model matrix that is not of full rank